# How to make checkboxes in Leaflet layers control behave like radio buttons

Tags: javascript, leaflet

Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/anton9ov/twxx4up8/

I have two baseLayers and two overLayers with sets of markers on my map. I want to make checkboxes switching overLayers behave like radio buttons. I.e. I want to achieve selected only one of them at the same time.

```
L.control.layers({
    "Map 1": basemap1,
  "Map 2": basemap2
}, {
    "Marker 1": markerLayer1,
  "Marker 2": markerLayer2
}).addTo(map);
```

Comment: See [this question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/180644/56906) on GIS.SE. Basically, you listen for an `overlayadd` event and check which layer is being added, then remove the other(s). It requires a timeout for some reason, but it works. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/gwulo/5euduuun/1/

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite [L.Control.Layers](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/master/src/control/Control.Layers.js) and replace

```
input = document.createElement('input');
input.type = 'checkbox';
input.className = 'leaflet-control-layers-selector';
input.defaultChecked = checked;
```

with

```
input = this._createRadioElement('leaflet-control-layers-selector', checked);
```

Check this [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/M58D0QkSRZeateg4UY9m?p=preview)

This example based on your jsfiddle is quick and dirty but it gets down to writing your own control.

Answer (score -1):

You can directly edit the leaflet.js file (Line 4388) as shown below for the desired output.

Replace

```
t.overlay ? (i = e.createElement("input"), i.type = "checkbox", i.className = "leaflet-control-layers-selector", i.defaultChecked = s) : i = this._createRadioElement("leaflet-base-layers", s), i.layerId = o.stamp(t.layer), o.DomEvent.on(i, "click", this._onInputClick, this);
```

with

```
t.overlay ? (i = this._createRadioElement('leaflet-control-layers-selector', s)) : i = this._createRadioElement("leaflet-base-layers", s), i.layerId = o.stamp(t.layer), o.DomEvent.on(i, "click", this._onInputClick, this);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I am not sure why this answer got downvote, there should have been a comment to explain if it is not useful